# Online courses for advanced statistics/econometrics with Python?

Tags: python, references, econometrics

I am searching for intermediate/advanced online courses in statistics/econometrics that employ python. Exploring the main platforms (i.e. Coursera, Edx, etc..) I found either very basic courses that use python or more intermediate/advanced courses that use R. Anyone here aware of where I could look for this?

Comment: Please do not repeat the same question again!

Comment: I thought it was not clear as the only comment I got was about logistic regression

Comment: A lot of economics has to do with causal inference such as to measure the average treatment effect. The best source for this, which includes examples related to econometrics, would be: https://matheusfacure.github.io/python-causality-handbook/landing-page.html

Comment: There are also books that implement econometric methods in Python. They are introductory though. See https://www.amazon.com/Using-Python-Introductory-Econometrics-Florian/dp/B08924H17Y/ref=sr_1_3?crid=1MRA8EOGSL28B&keywords=econometrics+python&qid=1675424108&sprefix=econometrics+p%2Caps%2C868&sr=8-3

Comment: The Effect by Nick Hutington-Klein also has Python code: https://www.amazon.com/Effect-Nick-Huntington-Klein/dp/1032125780/ref=sr_1_1?crid=1F03B9BR6KJVJ&keywords=the+effect&qid=1675424316&sprefix=the+effe%2Caps%2C474&sr=8-1

Comment: Causal Inference: the mixtape also has Python code. But the text itself has too many errors for one to learn smoothly: https://mixtape.scunning.com/